# change value inside quotes in xml file from bash

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I'm writing a bash script to streamline an installation.

I want to replace the old database settings in an xml file with a new value.
But I don't manage to get it right.

original string: url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"

script:

```
read -e -p "Enter the ORACLE SID: " -i "orcl" ORACLE_SID_VALUE
sed -i  '/url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/c\url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:$ORACLE_SID_VALUE"' /home/server/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/server.xml
```

result in xml file: url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:$ORACLE_SID_VALUE"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: sed might work for you in this instance but you should consider using an XML tool to do this. If you show the structure of your XML, someone will be able to advise you on how to do that.

Comment: I'm open for suggestion. But the main thing is that it have to be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables inside single quotes are not read as variables. For example, `echo '$a'` will print `$a` on the terminal. But `echo "$a"` will print value of `$a` in the terminal.

Here, I'm putting your variable outside single quotes

```
sed -i  '/url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/c\url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:'${ORACLE_SID_VALUE}'"' /home/server/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/server.xml
```

It should work, though not tested.

Comment: Can you please tell, what it gives as result?

Comment: sorry, wrong of me, it worked. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not expanded in single quotes. Use double quotes for the variable:

```
sed -i  '/url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/c\url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:'"$ORACLE_SID_VALUE"'"' \
   /home/server/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/server.xml
```

Comment: @LarsGrotell: Works for me. Are you sure you copied and pasted the code correctly?

Comment: sorry, wrong of me, it worked. Thanks you very much.